# Set I18n key scope differing from the template scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rails-i18n

I would like to render the same template, i.e. `wonderful_email`, applying two different translation scopes to it. In one context, I would like the `.subject` in the template to reference, say, `wonderful_email.subject`, and in another I would like it to reference
`other_email.subject` - even though the template is the same (it is just rendered from different places).

Is there some way to set the current I18n scope that defines the addressing of the "dot-prefix" keys in calls to `I18n.t()`? Preferably I'd do this outside of the template itself - in the rendering caller.